# how to save a cropped UIImage from my camera?

Tags: iphone, camera, overlay

In my app i am using camera functionality and i am using overlayview for camera every thing working fine.

The problem is while saving image i dont want to save the entire image i want save only the picture I'm showing within the overlayview.

Please see the difference between the two screens below.

**1) Here is what I am showing in the overlayview:**

[image: What's in the Overlay View]

**2) and here is what i am getting:**

[image: What I am Getting]

Thanks! in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to capture image merged by the camera ouput and its cameraOverlay in iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387586/how-to-capture-image-merged-by-the-camera-ouput-and-its-cameraoverlay-in-iphone)

Comment: bit i am not using AV Foundation Framework @SPVarma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CGRect rect = self.overlayimage.frame;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(self.overlayimage.frame.size.width, self.overlayimage.frame.size.height));
// This is where we resize captured image
[(UIImage *)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] drawInRect:rect];


captureimage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

make object of UIImagePickerController

```
imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
```

And get the cropped image in delegate method of UIImagePickerController

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
```

UIImage *croppedImg = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"];
}